# add table data <td> only to one row on ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-show

in a table with ng-repeat is it possible to add a cell only to one row?

in my code:

```
<tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="user in users ng-click="selectUser(user)">
            <td>{{user.username}}</td>
            <td><input type="text"....></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"...></td>
            <td><input type="submit" ...  ng-show="user==selectedUser" /></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

in this code I want the last `td` appears only on the selected row and does not affect other rows, is it possible? or it is JS or CSS thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you should be using the controller as syntax, it automatically puts everything in the controller under 1 object, which can cause issues with Angular. But I don't think that's the issue here.

The user you select could be equal to the selectedUser, but if they aren't pointing to the same reference, they won't be able. If usernames are distinct I'd change the ng-show="user.username == selectedUser.username"
and that should work fine.

Comment: the problem is not with controller or scope or method , the issue is the ng-repeat directive , that applies the column to all rows, not only the selected row

Comment: Then are you sure the ng-show isn't on the <td> element? The way the code is written up there, the column will always be there, but the input box will only show if the row is selected.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/c0IMZqZL1OZrJr1KJD9e?p=preview

This is pretty much what you have up there, what part isn't working as expected?

Comment: after the submit input add another td , for instance again                      <td>{{user.username}}</td>
you will see that on click , the middle column will be added to all rows
what I want is the middle column just be added to the slected row not all the rows

Comment: I do not see any differences !

Comment: '<td>{{user.username}}</td>'
'<td><input type="submit" ng-show="user==selectedUser" /></td>'
'<td>{{user.username}}</td>'

Comment: I'm not following what the issue is. With what you just pasted if you select a row, the button only appears on one row, but the rest are accounting for the space of the button. Which leaves empty space in the other rows.

It seems like you're saying the problem is that white space in the other rows. In which the plunkr does not have that.

If that's not the issue, then I'm lost.

Comment: maybe I have problem in explaining :D 
yes I DO NOT WANT that white space in other rows, neither I do not want the column related to button in other rows , just the cell with button be added on the selected row

Comment: I updated the plunkr again, when using ng-show the column is there, but hidden on the other rows, with ng-if the column isn't even being rendered.
Does that fix the issue?

Comment: as I click on the given link of plnkr above I see the same code as before
would you plz send me new link

Comment: Thanks man, this was what I wanted :D though it does not work on my app and adds the column to all rows again,  but as long as the plunker version works is enough for now

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, it seems like your code is mostly correct, but you're using `selectedUser` as a function and as an object representation of user. Maybe your function would be called `selectUser` which would set `$scope.selectedUser`. `ng-show="user == selectedUser"` would make since then.

I'm personally not a big fan of having conditions in the view, so I'd have a function in the controller which does the comparison and returns true or false.

```
function isSelectedUser(user) {
    return user == $scope.selectedUser;
}
```

then you can just use `ng-show="isSelectedUser(user)"`

Comment: yes correct the function is selectUser(user), the ng-show works fine now. but at the refresh my table has 3 columns and on clicking any row the 4th appears. I want the 4th column appear only on the selected row and not the whole table with empty content

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what issue you're having right now. The code should show the submit button only in the row you click, isn't that happening?

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery to append the `<td>` on the selected row `<tr>`. The `:nth-child()` is an easy way for you to select a row.

```
var selectedRow = 2;
$('tbody tr:nth-child('+ selectedRow +')').append('<td><input type="submit" /></td>');
```

Comment: what is the angular way ?

Comment: Alex's answer is the angular way.  
You also said that "I want the 4th column appear only on the selected row and not the whole table with empty content". That means your rows will have different number of cells - some of them having 3 while others have 4. I'm pretty sure that tables with rows with different number of cells `<td>` is not possible.

Comment: is "now" or  "not" possible ?

Comment: aha , thank that was exactly my question , rows with different number of cells or columns

Comment: if you really want to force rows with different number of columns you can check this out = (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34668057/add-table-data-td-only-to-one-row-on-ng-repeat/34668151#34668151)